# Microsoft Outlook 2011 deletes e-mails after 7 days

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2011

A client of us has the problem that Outlook (2011 for mac) automatically deletes all emails older than 7 days from her INBOX. If the e-mail is in the trash, the e-mails aren't being deleted.

There is no rule or similar configured in Outlook. Does anyone have an idea where this could be configured?

Thanks a lot

Kind regards

Comment: Try looking in File > Options > Advanced > AutoArchive Settings... These are the default AutoArchive settings but you can also have custom AutoArchive settings for each folder... under File > Info > Cleanup Tools...

Comment: What type of email account is it? If it's IMAP or Exchange, what's the current setting for how long to keep "offline mail"?

Comment: Sorry just realized this Outlook 2011 for Mac.. not sure if my comment above still applies haven't used 2011 too much...

Comment: @CharlesH - I promise you.  Your comment is still valid for `Office 2011`.

Comment: it is disabled as well @CharlesH.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 it is an IMAP account. The E-Mails aren't on the server so they must been deleted by the client